# Windows 10 arbitrarily downscaling images and icons

Tags: windows-10, graphics

My installation of Windows 10 will occasionally start downscaling some images and icons. This is not specific to any program. It seems to happen most commonly to warm-colored images. I've tried rebooting, doesn't fix it. I've tried reinstalling my graphics driver (Nvidia), rarely fixes it. I've looked through webpage after webpage of graphics bugs on forums and cannot find anything similar to my problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “downscaling”? If possible, please provide a screenshot.

Comment: @DanielB I mean slightly downscaled. Not super obviously, but it happens.